# Why when I'm inserting a key frame it's adding only 1 but in the tutorial it's adding 4 ? How can I make it to insert 4 keys like in the tutorial?

Tags: animation, keyframes

My blender version is : 2.83.1

This is a screenshot from the tutorial on youtube he his doing right click on the offset and insert a keyframe. Like in frame 1 it's adding 4 keys same when he is doing in the frame 120.

[image: Tutorial keyframes]

This is a screenshot of my blender and it's adding only 1 keyframe on the first frame on frame 120.

[image: My blender side it's adding only 1 key]

Comment: You are inserting a key-frame into a single field, the Offset value of a Follow Path constraint, and therefore you see one diamond icon in the Timeline window. I think that is all you need, and you do not need to mach the tutorial video in this to get the desired result. Maybe the tutorial maker inserted keyframes in other fields as well, unseen to the viewer of the video. (If you provide a link to the tutorial i could probably determine this with a little more certainty.)

Comment: @Fjoersteller This is the link for the tutorial the keyframs part start at 2:05 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLqD2_cVdQM

Comment: That is really weird. I would expect there to only be one keyframe, and when i do it myself i also only get one keyframe. It's a bit of a mystery to me. However i don't think it's really a problem though. Like i said, you only need the one keyframe to do this. If you do experience any kind of problem, let me know.

Comment: @Fjoersteller I tried with one diamond the next problem is that the point light has no effect on the text like in the tutorial. Not sure if it's a bug in my blender version or something else is missing in the tutorial. I tried to add a material to the text I tried to change the light point radius size strength but nothing helped.  The point light is animating around also if one key frame at frame 1 offset 0.000 if I'm adding another key frame at frame 100 then the light is not moving around but moving only in a very small area of the track.  Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: The light moving on a small area of the track is strange. If I create the animation i have no problems so it is hard for me to to figure out what went wrong from your description alone. If you are willing to share your .blend file i'd be happy to take a look. (you can share it here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ) As for the the light having no effect, that is a whole other question entirely and it would be best to ask a separate new question for that. (and in that case it's also hard to determine the problem form description alone so i advise to then also share your file.)

Comment: @Fjoersteller Here is my blender file share link https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1ZqgQG71

Comment: I wrote an answer; hope it helps. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is: You only need the one key frame to achieve the desired result. : )

But I looked at your file and here are some tips to help make this work:

1. After you insert a keyframe on the Offset value 0 of the Follow Path constraint, you might also want to insert a keyframe on the Offset value 100 at another frame in the Timeline.  Here it means 100% of the path is traveled, so The difference between the Timeline frames will determine the length of one cycle ( how long it takes for the light to go around the curve once)
2. Press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> before you change the shape of the curve, otherwise you might also move its vertices in the z axis (and change their height), which could change things in an unwanted way.
3. Before you add the light (and also the curve actually) to the scene, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to move the 3D Cursor to the center of the scene. Then the light will be in the will be better aligned with the curve and the "moving in a very small area" will be reduced
4. Alternatively you can move the light close tho the curve and check the box next to Follow Curve in the Follow Path constraint. This will allow the light move either around or inside the curve depending on the distance between the light and the curve. (If you have the box checked next to Relationship Lines in the Viewport Overlays menu, you can see a dotted line between the light and the curve indicating this distance.)

Hope that helps : )

**Edit:**

I also realized the answer to the actual initial question : ) Why does it sometimes look like more keyframes are added? If you extent the panel on the left in the Timeline window (by clicking the tiny ">" icon) it will show a Summary of used keyframes. If you extend this summary, more diamond icons will be shown but they are the same key frames by a different name or UI location. If the summary is extended and the panel is hidden, it can give the illusion more keyframes are added.